# How to add list to list in Immutable.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutable.js

What is the best way to add List to List in [Immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js)?

`concat` method is working, but another way is not working.

```
const a = fromJS([  
                {
                    comment: 'aaaa',
                    who: 'a1',
                    buttonInfo: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
                },
               {
                    comment: 'bb',
                    who: 'a2',
                    buttonInfo: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
                },
            ]);

const b = fromJS([  
                {
                    comment: 'ccc',
                    who: 'c1',
                    buttonInfo: ['a', 'b'],
                },
               {
                    comment: 'ddd',
                    who: 'd2',
                    buttonInfo: ['a''],
                },
            ]);
```

This is working:

```
a.concat(b)
```

But this is not working:

```
[...a ,...b]

// or

b.map(v => {
  a.push(v);
})
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use concat method as it said in doc:

```js
const list1 = List([ 1, 2, 3 ]);
const list2 = List([ 4, 5, 6 ]);
const array = [ 7, 8, 9 ];
const list3 = list1.concat(list2, array);
// List [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]
```

Comment: depends what do you want. You can use both merge and concat cause:  "Immutable.js can treat any JavaScript Array or Object as a Collection". Basically you can also check: https://github.com/rtfeldman/seamless-immutable

Answer (score 0):

An ImmutableJS list has a method named concat whose behavior is the same as a normal javascript array. However, you cannot use spread syntax for an Immutable array.

Also the syntax for push is different from the normal array, push like concat with Immutable List returns a new list, your map method will look like

```
b.map(v => {
   a = a.push(v);
})
```

> P.S. Using the above method though will mutate your array `a`. You must create a new List and then push both the array contents into it if you want to use push. However `concat` is the best way for your case

Answer (score 0):

For add List to List in [Immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/), you can use `merge` method.

Example:

```
const a = fromJS(
  [  
    {
      comment: 'aaaa',
      who: 'a1',
      buttonInfo: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    },
    {
      comment: 'bb',
      who: 'a2',
      buttonInfo: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    },
  ]
);

const b = fromJS(
  [  
    {
      comment: 'ccc',
      who: 'c1',
      buttonInfo: ['a', 'b'],
    },
    {
      comment: 'ddd',
      who: 'd2',
      buttonInfo: ['a''],
    },
  ]
);


a.merge(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

After running tests on https://measurethat.net/, it seems that the concat method is more performant than spread.

By the way, the spread method should also work, but you will need to convert back to ImmutableJS:

```
Immutable.fromJS([...a, ...b])
```

Concat is the most straightforward and simple method in this case.